# Возможно ли открыть попап 1 раз, после регистрации пользователя Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

После регистрации пользователя его редиректит на определенную страницу на которую к слову пользователь может попасть раньше чем зарегистрируется.. Нужно только 1 раз открыть попап после регистрации спустя определенный промежуток времени. Не могу придумать как это осуществить.

Comment: Почитайте что такое куки, локальное хранилище...

Comment: @DaemonHK Да.. Видимо это единственный возможный вариант. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. При первом заходе на сайт зафиксировать куку пользователя либо же сохранить цифровой отпечаток пользователя
2. Зафиксировать у пользователя показ попапа в куках либо в базе по ключу фингерпринет
3. При авторизации пользователя - перенести соответствующую информацию в мета данные - add_user_meta()